# Admin dashboard layout problem

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, moderator-tools

I'm looking at the flags page on the admin dashboard on Programmers SE and the right panel with the # of flags, links to chat, etc. is way down at the bottom of the page below the last flag entry:

[image]

This is in Chrome 10.0.648.204, Windows 7, 1920x1200.

Comment: I reported this to Marc Gravell a week ago, on IE8 on XP. He said it was being looked at. Guess it's not quite resolved yet.

Comment: I think this is site-specific; I recall having this issue on English, but never on SO. So it sounds like a Jin thing.

Comment: Sorry I missed this. is this still happening? I can't repro this in Chrome(both OSX and Win) on the Programmers or the English site.

Comment: @Jin Yes, it's still happening. I just tried again and it's happening on Programmers. It looks liked the side panel rendered at the top at first and then jumped down. Chrome 12.0.742.100, Win 7, 1600x1200.